# strlen to return size_t?

Tags: c, string, strlen

In C:
My string length function is returning a `size_t` value?

Why is it not returning a integer which is conventional? And one more thing I noticed was that when I was trying concatenate this string with another string I received a bus error when I ran the program.

Context: I was kind of playing with gmp library and converting big numbers to strings and I end up with the above situation.

What kind of a string is that? Is my operating system playing a role in this issue? I use a MAC, 64-bit OS.

Edited: The error message I received was:

```
: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t’
```

Thanks!

@all: Thanks for the answers but I thought I will put the bus error as another question because it seems to be a different issue.

Comment: `size_t` _is_ an integer data type. the bus error most likely has absolutely nothing to do with that, you're probably simply overruning a buffer, have a dangling/null pointer somewhere or something to that effect.

Comment: @Mat the integer part is clarified now, but bus error is becoming common for any program i use strcat for two character pointers.

Comment: open a new question for that specifically, with some code snippets that show how you use `strcat`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is `int` might be not wide enough to store the whole range of possible length values. For example on 64-bit you can have a string longer than 4 gigabytes and if `int` is 32 bit you can't possibly return length of such a long string via an `int` variable.

Answer (score 3):

POSIX `strlen()` [does return `size_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strlen.html).

As to what's caused the bus error, it's impossible to say without seeing the code and knowing more details about the exact nature of your changes. One possibility is that you've caused a buffer overrun or did something with a `NULL` pointer you shouldn't have done.

Comment: @sharptooth: Thank u! Any ideas about how to debug the bus error?

Comment: @Maverickgugu: Running the program in gdb or looking at the core dump might be a good start.

Answer (score 3):

`strlen()` always returned `size_t` ... and the POSIX standard also says that.

I guess the reason is that `int` has sign and the capacity of even an `unsigned int` might not be enough for holding size of an element (say if you have a 32bit int on x86-64 with 16GB RAM) ... the example is extreme, but possible.

Answer (score 2):

`strlen()` returns a `size_t` since at least ISO C90 -- I just checked in my copy.  And this standard should have no technical difference with ANSI C89.

There was a change of convention (`size_t` wasn't in K&R C), but it was a long time ago.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized it now.. 
Is it advisable to give ISO-C90 a full reading. or use it as a reference as issues comes up!

Answer (score 2):

To address your warning (which is actually an error - you've invoked undefined behavior by passing the wrong type to `printf`) you should use `%zu` rather than `%d` for printing `size_t` values.

Comment: Yes.. I realized that size_t can be printed using %ld.. But %zu also seems to be good option. Thanks!

Comment: `%ld` is not necessarily correct. In fact it will give warnings on most 32-bit systems where `size_t` is defined as `unsigned int` - even though the type sizes are they same here, `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` are still not *the same type*.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple and logical reason for all of the functions from the standard library to work with `size_t` when it comes to lengths of memory blocks - the built-in `sizeof` operator yields a `size_t` result as well.

Moreover, `size_t` is unsigned, of a particular size, tied to the architecture and is semantically different than just a generic `int` which is meant for storing any number from the count of trees around your office to your SO reputation.

Comment: I don't know that an `int` is guaranteed to be sufficient to store SO rep. Isn't it guaranteed to be able to store at least `-32768` to `+32767`? :p

Comment: @Thomas  _Minimum_ range for an `int` is -32767 to +32767 C11 §5.2.4.2.1.