# Print statement with for loop and if statement

Tags: c, string, for-loop

I need to determine whether or not a user input is numeric. I need to loop over each characters and check if all are digits, if not `printf()` Error message, or else Successful. I used a for loop to loop over each characters and an `if` statement with `isdigit()` function to check the digit. But my problem is I am printing for each characters. For example, if I enter `22A`, I get 2 Successful messages for `2` and `2`, and then I get Error message for `A`. But I need just print the error message since `22A` is not entirely numeric.

```
    int n = strlen(argv[1]);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if (isdigit((int)argv[1][i]) == 0){
            printf("Error\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            printf("Success\n");
            printf("%i\n", atoi(argv[1]));   
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are printing "Success" inside the loop, so it is still just a partial success.

Comment: @bruno: (a) `atol` will not do the job of determining whether a string is numeric. It accepts an initial numeric portion and provides no indication of whether that is the entire string or not. (b) Even if it did, it fails to meet a stated requirement: “I need to loop over each…” The goal is not merely to convert a string to a number but to perform an exercise, likely for a class in which in the OP is a student. Calling a library routine fails to teach how to use the control structures being taught.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I wanted to say **strtol**, is not the first time I do that error damned

Comment: You don't want to print "Success" until after you've examined *all* the characters in the string, meaning you want to want until *after* the loop has finished.

Comment: When you say *numeric* are you restricting this to just digits, or are you allowed a prefixed `-`, a decimal separator, and possibly even thousands separators? Then there's scientific notation to worry about. Do please clarify, then it's answerable.

Comment: @Bathsheba: “I need to loop over each characters and check if all are digits”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: But on the other hand "I need to determine whether or not a user input is numeric." I read the second sentence as an implementation technique.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use another way, you could use [`strspn()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strspn) from `string.h`.

```
size_t n = strlen(argv[1]);
if(strspn(argv[1], "0123456789")==n)
{
    printf("Success\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Error\n");
}
```

`strspn()` returns the number of bytes in the initial segment of the first argument string which consist only of bytes f
rom the second argument string, which in this case are the numbers.

So, if the value returned by `strspn()` is same as the length of the string, the string has no non-digit characters.

---

`strlen()` returns not exactly an `int`. It is a `size_t`. It is better to use the latter instead. See [strlen to return size_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5716774/5375464).